# align <span> between two <input> elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### ISSUE

Using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 there is an issue that can be seen below.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input class="span5" type="text" id="1" />  
        <span class="span3">...</span>
        <input class="span4" type="text" id="2" />
    </div>
</body>
```

To me this should make an input textbox, then ... then another input textbox...however, with bootstrap it makes `...` then an input, then another input.

---

### Examples

**Example of Error:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/130/)

**Expected Result:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8DeL/)

Comment: @GalenNare the examples show what it is doing and what I want it to do, please explain what more you want. I just want the order of the elements to be with bootstrap 2.3.2 input, span, input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Adding the style `float:left` resolved the weird issue due to span auto adding this float.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input style="float:left;" class="span5" type="text" id="1" />  
        <span class="span3">...</span>
        <input style="float:left;" class="span4" type="text" id="2" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**Demo:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/133/)

Answer (score 0):

The span classes you are using on the the inputs and ellipsis elements are block elements and are used with Bootstraps grid system to layout your content.

See:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: i'm using the grid system http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem